# Scaling / parametric weighting function for time series analysis

Tags: function, math, time-series, scaling, weighted

I have some time series data and I would like to weight my data, so that recent observations are weighted higher than older observations. Therefor I'm looking for a parametric weighting function, which satisfy a few properties. It should look like this:

> **weighting(time, minTime, maxTime, minWeight, slope)** = ?

whereby

- **time** is obviously the time of the observation to weight and should be between minTime and maxTime (time >= minTime, time <= maxTime),
- **minTime** is the oldest observation time,
- **maxTime** is the newest observation time,
- **minWeight** is the minimum weight to return (and also the intercept with the weight axis; interval: [0,1]),
- **slope** adjusts the shape of the curve.

**Output:**
The output should be in the interval [minWeight, 1.0].

[image: <image2>]

Does anyone have an idea, how this weighting function might look like, or some hints or code examples / pseudocode?

---

Some functions I have looked at:

- A root or power functions like

> **f(x) = x^(n/m)**, if n < m    -- root function
>
> **f(x) = x^(n/m)**, if n = m    -- linear function
>
> **f(x) = x^(n/m)**, if n > m    -- power function

[image]

- [Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), [logarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) or [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) functions...
- [Rescaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) (min-max normalization) also satisfies a few of those properties:

> rescaling(time, minTime, maxTime) = (time - minTime) / (maxTime -
>   minTime)

This weighting function provides a weight in the interval [0, 1]. But the curve shape is always linear (and cannot be adjusted) and the minimum value is always 0 (I also would like to adjust that).

I guess I'm too stupid to get all the parts together. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be simplified by introducing new axes, `t'` and `w'`, as illustrated here

[image]

With these coordinates the equations are simple:

```
w'^2 = t'       - high-score
w' = t'         - normal-score
w' = t'^2       - low-score
```

so, it only remains to replace `w'` with: `(w - w0)/(1 - w0)` and `t'` with: `(t - t0)/(t1 - t0)` to get:

```
(w - w0)^2/(1 - w0)^2 = (t - t0)/(t1 - t0)      - high-score
(w - w0)/(1 - w0) = (t - t0)/(t1 - t0)          - normal-score
(w - w0)/(1 - w0) = (t - t0)^2 / (t1 - t0)^2    - low-score
```

Now we have to solve for `w`:

```
w = w0 + (1 - w0)sqrt((t - t0)/(t1 - t0))       - high-slope
w = w0 + (1 - w0)(t - t0)/(t1 - t0)             - normal-slope
w = w0 + (1 - w0)(t - t0)^2 / (t1 - t0)^2       - low-slope
```

The very same technique can be used if you choose another functions instead of `sqrt()` and `^2`.

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation and the help. Now I have the following weighting function, which satisfies all properties:

weighting(time, minTime, maxTime, minWeight, slope) = minWeight + (1 - minWeight) * ((time - minTime) / (maxTime - minTime))^slope